# Efficient method to zero or clear elements of dynamically allocated struct

Tags: c, struct

Within a for loop, I am wishing to pass a dynamically allocated `struct` to a function.  At each iteration I wish to zero or clear the elements of the struct before the next iteration and function call.  I have tried moving the `malloc` inside the loop and free the struct at the end of each loop, but this doesn't clear the struct. I have also tried `memset(counts, 0, sizeof(counts))`, but this doesn't set the elements to zero.

Header file:

```
typedef struct counts{
    int base_counts[6]; 
    int n1;
    int n2;
    size_t L_tot_bases;
    int L_bad_site;
}counts;
```

In file

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, row_count = 5;;
    struct counts *bulk_counts;
    bulk_counts = malloc(sizeof(counts));
        for (i = 0; i < row_count; ++i){
            get_counts(bulk_counts);
        }
}


void get_counts(counts *bulk_counts{
  bulk_counts->base_counts[0] = 3;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` for allocation and `memset(bulk_counts, 0, sizeof *bulk_counts)` just before `free(bulk_counts);` if desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `memset()` was the right approach, and absolutely will set all the bits (and therefore all the values, since they're integers) to zero.  For example:

```
struct counts *bulk_counts = malloc(sizeof(counts));
for (i = 0; i < row_count; ++i) {
    memset(bulk_counts, 0, sizeof(counts));
    get_counts(bulk_counts);
}
```

Then again, no need for dynamic allocation, you can do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < row_count; ++i) {
    struct counts bulk_counts = {0}; // all members will be zero
    get_counts(&bulk_counts);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using calloc() will be one approach, it will not only allocate memory but also initialize the memory with zero however memory allocation is an expensive operation.
memset approach is the right choice, it will set entire block by zero.

the thing you doing wrong is you are not passing pointer to memset!, it should be done like this:

```
memset(bulk_counts, 0, sizeof(counts))
```

Comment: Using the pattern `memset(bulk_counts, 0, sizeof *bulk_counts);` ensures that you never cause a buffer overflow

Comment: @MattMcNabb how can a buffer overflow occurs in this case?

Comment: If `bulk_counts` was not actually of type `counts` then this could overflow

Comment: I guess thats obvious for the programmer to give the corresponding data type but yes your approach is safe one.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign whole structs by value in C:

```
for (i = 0; i < row_count; ++i){
    *bulk_counts = ((counts){})
    get_counts(bulk_counts);
}
```

...so all you need to do is assign to `*bulk_counts` from another struct with all-zero members. The syntax above uses a `counts` literal (missing elements are automatically zero); you could also e.g. create a named one before the loop, and use that.

Since this uses basic assignment, it should be no slower than any other way; fastest if there's any measurable difference (it would be a pretty dumb compiler that used suboptimal code for a builtin feature).